# Can't write to brand new drive?

Tags: partitioning, mount, kubuntu, steam

I've decided to make the plunge into Kubuntu in lieu of "upgrading" to Windows 10/11 with very little experience with Linux, and I've run into trouble quite early.

In short, I want to use this as my main PC from which I stream Steam games, among other things.

Everything was going swimmingly with my install until it came time to make a new Steam Library folder on my secondary NVMe drive. I tried creating a folder with Steam and it gave me an error that the drive was read-only.

I thought surely Steam must be bugged, so I went to make the folder myself via the Kubuntu GUI. Nope, read only. Mind you this is on a fresh install, brand new drive I just mounted as ext4 for maximum compatibility with Steam. Steam will let me install stuff on my primary drive just fine, but neither it nor I can create a new folder via GUI on nvme0n1.

I've done unmounting, remounting, via command line terminal and GUI (via KDE Partition Manager), and I'm becoming very frustrated. Here's the results from some commands I found were commonly asked about in similar questions:

```
username@username-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-swap_1: 2051MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  2051MB  2051MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root: 998GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  998GB  998GB  ext4


Model: CT1000P3SSD8 (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32              boot, esp
 2      538MB   1000GB  1000GB                     lvm


Model: INTEL SSDPEKNW010T8 (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 1024GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags


username@username-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo fsck /dev/nvme1n1
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/nvme1n1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a gpt partition table in /dev/nvme1n1

username@username-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 61.96 MiB, 64970752 bytes, 126896 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 63.23 MiB, 66301952 bytes, 129496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 163.29 MiB, 171225088 bytes, 334424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 238.43 MiB, 250015744 bytes, 488312 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 400.8 MiB, 420265984 bytes, 820832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 346.33 MiB, 363151360 bytes, 709280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 91.69 MiB, 96141312 bytes, 187776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: INTEL SSDPEKNW010T8                     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D4E53ED1-F214-2B48-967F-0432400645C1


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: CT1000P3SSD8                            
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0A634D48-6E20-4CF5-B5B6-C1F09A298087

Device           Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 1953523711 1952473088  931G Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root: 929.1 GiB, 997611012096 bytes, 1948459008 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-swap_1: 1.91 GiB, 2051014656 bytes, 4005888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop8: 49.62 MiB, 52031488 bytes, 101624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

For the record, I have no idea what those tons of /dev/loop#s are, but from a cursory web search it doesn't seem like they're likely to be the culprit.

I also don't understand why Linux/Kubuntu apparently mounted a third, virtual drive in the form of /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root, but I'm sure it's perfectly logical to someone who has any idea what they're doing, unlike myself. I made the plunge into Linux without so much as learning the difference between /dev/ and /root/ and such, which believe me I plan to learn in the next few hours/days.

For now... if you would kindly help me just get a big ol' game installed on /nvme1n1, I'd very much appreciate it.

Edit on 12/23/22 @ 1231 ET : Steps taken since reading the first two comments:

```
Create a new partition table (type: gpt) on ‘/dev/nvme1n1’ 
Job: Create new partition table on device ‘/dev/nvme1n1’ 
Command: sfdisk --wipe=always /dev/nvme1n1 
Create new partition table on device ‘/dev/nvme1n1’: Success
Create a new partition table (type: gpt) on ‘/dev/nvme1n1’: Success

Create a new partition (488.28 GiB, ext4) on ‘/dev/nvme1n1’ 
Job: Create new partition on device ‘/dev/nvme1n1’ 
Command: sfdisk --force --append /dev/nvme1n1 

Command: sfdisk --list --output Device,UUID /dev/nvme1n1 
Create new partition ‘/dev/nvme1n1p1’: Success

Job: Create file system ‘ext4’ on partition ‘/dev/nvme1n1p1’ 
Command: mkfs.ext4 -qF /dev/nvme1n1p1 

Command: sfdisk --part-type /dev/nvme1n1 1 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4 
Create file system ‘ext4’ on partition ‘/dev/nvme1n1p1’: Success

Job: Set the file system label on partition ‘/dev/nvme1n1p1’ to "SteamLibrary" 
Command: e2label /dev/nvme1n1p1 SteamLibrary 
Set the file system label on partition ‘/dev/nvme1n1p1’ to "SteamLibrary": Success

Job: Check file system on partition ‘/dev/nvme1n1p1’ 
Command: e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/nvme1n1p1 
Check file system on partition ‘/dev/nvme1n1p1’: Success
Create a new partition (488.28 GiB, ext4) on ‘/dev/nvme1n1’: Success
```

Still can't create a new folder in that partition. The option is greyed out if I right-click to "create new," and when I went into Properties->Permissions->Advanced Permissions for the new partition, it has a table like so:

| Type  | Name | r | w | x | Effective |

| ----  | ---- | - | - | - | --------- |

| Owner | | X | X | X | rwx |

| Owning Group | | X |  | X | r-x|

| Others | | X |  | X | r-x |

Comment: I'd avoid the volume group/logical volume complication unless you really need it (raid, encryption).  Then understand the difference between a disk (/dev/nvme1n1) and a partition (/dev/nvme1n1p1). Partitions get filessytem made on them, get mounted, and get checked, not disks.

Comment: Loop devices are from snaps. I do not allows snaps on my Kubuntu system and have not missed anything yet. Had to convert Firefox. You are not showing any partitions on nvme1n1?? You need to create at least one partition, format to ext4 (or other Linux format) and give yourself ownership & permissions to that partition(s). I prefer not to totally use entire drive initially with my partitions for future changes, but that is a user preference. Use gparted to create partition(s), It already looks like gpt which is good. Gparted will also format it.

Comment: @ubfan1 I'm definitely not using RAID, I just did mostly default options for a fresh Kubuntu install. Not entirely sure what volume grouping is, to be honest. I can try to figure out how to disable it if you think it'll help!

Comment: @oldfred I don't know how to forbid snaps and I don't know what enabled/uses them on this brand spankin' new Kubuntu install. After reading your comment I realized the last step I did before coming here for help was in fact clearing out the partition. I'll try to figure out how to give myself permissions when I try making one again momentarily.

Comment: One way to use a data partition(s). https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk Back with XP, I had two, one NTFS for any data I wanted in both systems and one for Linux. I now have one data and one photos only as that grow so much & continues to grow the most. Something about grandkids.  You can see snaps: `snap list` and convert Firefox: 
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Thank you for the links @oldfred; I have some reading to do, and at a cursory glance they seem very similar to the issue(s) I've got going on so they will likely be extremely helpful.